# Bash Scripting: Replace (or delete) string in a file if line starts with (or matches) another string

Tags: linux, bash, string

Assuming an ini-style file like this,

```
[Group]
Icon=xxx.ico
Title=An Image Editor
Description=Manipulates .ico, .png and .jpeg images
```

I want to replace/delete ".ico" ONLY in the line that starts with (or matches) "Icon="

I was trying this:

```
oldline="`cat "$file" | grep "Icon="`"
newline="`echo "$oldline" | tr ".ico" ".png"`"
cat "$oldfile" | tr "$oldline" "$newline" > $file
```

Then i realized that `tr` works completely different than i thought. Its NOT a tradicional "replace this for that" function. So i guess the correct way is using `sed`. But:

- Ive never used `sed`before. No idea how it works. Is it overkill?
- If the most indicated way is really using `sed`, given it is so powerful, is there any elegant way to accomplish this rather than this "fetch line -> modify line -> replace oldline for newline in file" approach?

Notes:

- I cant replace ".ico" globally, i know that would be a LOT easier, i must restrict the replace to the Icon line, otherwise the Description line would be changed too.
- Im new to shell scripting in Linux, so im looking not only to the solution itself, but also for the "proper" way to do it.  Elegant, easy to read, conventional, etc

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Thank you guys! Here is the final script, as a reference:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Fix the following WARNING in ~/.xsession-errors
# gnome-session[2035]: EggSMClient-WARNING: Desktop file '/home/xxx/.config/autostart/skype.desktop' has malformed Icon key 'skype.png'(should not include extension)

file="$HOME/.config/autostart/skype.desktop"

if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    if `cat "$file" | grep "Icon=" | grep -q ".png"` ; then
        sed -i.bak '/^Icon=/s/\.png$//' "$file"
        cp "$file" "$PWD"
        cp "${file}.bak" "$PWD"     
    else
        echo "Nothing to fix! (maybe fixed already?)"
    fi  
else
    echo "Skype not installed (yet...)"
fi
```

MUCH sleeker than my original! The only thing i regret is that `sed` backup does not preserve original file timestamp. But i can live with that.

And, for the record, yes, ive created this script to fix an actual "bug" in Skype packaging.

Comment: sed is not a requirement... it was just a guess, because ive seen it used in many places for string manipulation. But im open to any idea. Maybe awk? Or some neat-bash-function-ive-never-heard-about? Anyway... no matter what the solution is, please explain the syntax in detail, so i know how to adapt and generalize it for similar tasks. Anyway, im reading man sed right now. The "/address/s/find/replace" format looks easier to use than the "all-in-one-regex" approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the following in sed should do what you need. First we check if the line starts with `Icon=` and if it does then we run the `s` command (i.e. substitute).

```
sed -i '/^Icon=/s/\.ico$/.png/' file
```

---

**Edit:** The sed script above can also be written like this:

```
/^Icon=/ {             # Only run the following block when this matches
    s/\.ico$/.png/     # Substitute '.ico' at the end of the line with '.png'
}
```

See [this page](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-27) for more details on how to restrict when commands are run.

Comment: don't forget to escape the period since this is in the pattern space

Comment: Though this works on this specific situation, I would put a backslash before the dot. In sed a simple dot means 'any character'.

Comment: I've escaped the dot now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But... care to explain the solution in more detail? Im overwhelmed with all these / \ ^ $. sed is very hard to read for a newcomer. Im not sure of what is a separator, what is a scape, what is a command...

Comment: Ok, let me see if i got this right: 
- sed is divided in "blocks" separated by "/"
- 1st block is empty - why? And what is it for?
- 2nd block is the regex for line matching, and ^ means "starting with"?
- 3rd will be the "replace from" string. But if ".ico" was a variable, how could i have scaped the "." ? Is there any way to "prepare" a given string for sed? Or to generalize this solution?
- 4th block is empy, meaning it will delete the ".ico" right? So to replace for ".png" should i use /\.png/ instead of // ?

Comment: I think you mean `'/^Icon=/s/\.ico$/.png/'` since the questioner wants to replace the extension, not remove it.  I think it would be worth expanding on this answer a little, since many people who've just used sed with the `s/.../.../` command might not be aware that you can prefix it with an address...

Comment: Great! Now i get it. The last piece of the puzzle was the $, now it can understand each and every character of the solution. By the way, Im new here, cant i choose both as accepted solutions? I wouldnt have learned so much about sed without @Steven 's kind explanations and references.

Answer (score 3):

sed is pretty easy to deal with. Here's one way:

```
sed 's/^\(Icon=.*\)\.ico$/\1.png/'
```

By default, sed works on every line in the file one at a time. The 's/.../.../' will do a regular expression match on the first argument and replace it with the second argument. The \1 stands for everything that matched the first group, which is demarcated by the parenthesis. You have to escape the parens with \.

The above works as part of a pipeline, but you can add an '-i' flag, like this

```
sed -i 's/^\(Icon=.*\)\.ico$/\1.png/' input.txt
```

to have it replace the file input.txt in place. Don't add that until you have tested your sed script a little.

Comment: Thanks for it! Specially for the detailed explanation. But... i was able to follow it only until the "s/.../.../" part. But, if the 2nd part "\1.png" replaces the 1st, I dont want to replace the "Icon=", just the ".ico" part of the line. And what is this "group" concept? Also, what are the "^\(" and ".*\)\" for? Man, those are a LOT of characters just for (presumably) scaping. Sorry for being so noobish... sed really looks tough to me...

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, there are a lot of components there that I've been working with for a while, so I don't tend to see the difficulties for a new user. But rest assured that the pieces come together in time.

Most of the funky characters come from the world of regular expressions, so maybe a [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on those would help get you going. There's a page on groups and backreferences there, too. I know it seems like a lot of characters, but once you get familiar with everything, it gets easy.